# Override Spring XML Property with Java Code

Tags: java, spring

I currently have a default properties file defined in my Spring XML file. I also have a number of integration tests that each need to use a specific properties files that are different from the default.

What is the best way for each test to override this and specify the properties file that needs to be used?

I tried using the Java annotation:

```
    @PropertySource({ "classpath:integrationTest.properties" })
```

But the test still loads the default properties file defined in my XML.

Comment: why not create a seperate spring file for unit testing?

Comment: 3.7.2.2. Example: the PropertyOverrideConfigurer
This Might Be Helpful for You http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-overrideconfigurer

Comment: What spring version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Spring 3.12.13 and if possible I'm trying to stay away from creating another spring XML file

Comment: I can't find this version, are you sure you didn't type any extra characters? Also please use @username when replying to someone so they get notified.

Comment: @Morfic sorry the version is 3.2.13, my mistake

Comment: I usually use separate spring profiles for dev & release with corresponding property files. However if you can upgrade to 4.1 looks like they added [@TestPropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html) which can easily override a configuration done with `@Config` & `@PropertySource`. More on this [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html)